# Is it easy/possible to produce XHTML 1.0 Strict with JSF?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, facelets

For a new project, the client has mandated the use of XHTML 1.0 Strict. Is it possible (or even easy) to meet this requirement with JSF? AFAIK Facelets exclusively uses XHTML internally, so it seems it should be reasonably easy. What about component libraries? Are they guaranteed (or can be made) to produce valid XHTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like producing XHTML Strict is at the moment not possible and [the issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-404) has been given very low priority by the development community... :(